# oracle apex change value of textfield automatically

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In oracle apex, i have two textflelds, one is for client id, and other is for client name.

I want that when I put the client id , client name's textfield should show the value automatically by fetching from the table.

i have tried it by using function, but failed

```
create or replace function clientname_byid(c_id in number)
return varchar2
is
cname varchar2(25);
begin
select client_name into cname from client_data where client_id = c_id;
return cname;
end;
```

and call this function in the clientname textfield by

```
select clientname_byid(:P2_CLIENT_ID) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a "Set value" dynamic action on `P2_CLIENT_ID` item.
- Use `SELECT` statement you wrote above, slightly modified:

  ```
  select client_name from client_data where client_id = :P2_CLIENT_ID;
  ```
- Don't forget to set dynamic action's "Items to submit" to `P2_CLIENT_ID`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: It is, for me. Please, create a workspace on apex.oracle.com, provide login credentials and someone will take a look at what you did and why it doesn't work.